FastAPI unit testing: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
I try to test my FastAPI application. I use a real postgres test database so I actually want to read/write data from/to the database instead of mocking.
The first test works fine. However the second test will always give me this error:
FAILED tests/users/test_signup.py::test_signup_successful2 - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

The first and second test are basically identical to assure it is not the fault of the test logic. I assume it has something to do with the client that I'm using. I was facing difficulties before as I was not able to get the FastAPI TestClient to work. Therefore I switched to the AsyncClient which works for one test only for some reason and I don't know why.
This is how my code currently looks like:
# tests/test_signup.py
import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient, get
from httpx._transports.asgi import ASGITransport
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from app import app 
from database.session import get_session



@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def client():
    """Fixture for creating a new test client."""
    transport = ASGITransport(app=app)
    async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="http://test") as client:
        yield client


@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def session():
    """Fixture for creating a new test session."""
    session: AsyncSession = await get_session().__anext__()  # Get the session
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        await session.close()  # Ensure the session is properly closed


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_signup_successful(client, session):
    """Test user signup with valid data"""
    # Use ASGITransport explicitly
    # transport = ASGITransport(app=app)
    # async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="http://test") as client:
    # Define the request payload
    payload = {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "username": "johndoe",
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "password": "strongpassword123"
    }
    # Perform POST request
    response = await client.post("/user/signup", json=payload)

    # Assertions
    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()
    assert data["email"] == payload["email"]
    assert "uuid" in data
    assert data["role"] == "user"

    # Verify the user exists in the database
    statement = text(f"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '{payload['email']}'")
    result = await session.exec(statement)
    user = result.scalar()
    assert user is not None
    await session.close()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_signup_successful2(client, session):
    """Test user signup with valid data"""
    # Use ASGITransport explicitly
    # transport = ASGITransport(app=app)
    # async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="http://test") as client:
    # Define the request payload
    payload = {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe2",
        "username": "johndoe2",
        "email": "testuser2@example.com",
        "password": "strongpassword123"
    }
    # Perform POST request
    response = await client.post("/user/signup", json=payload)

    # Assertions
    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()
    assert data["email"] == payload["email"]
    assert "uuid" in data
    assert data["role"] == "user"

    # Verify the user exists in the database
    statement = text(f"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '{payload['email']}'")
    result = await session.exec(statement)
    user = result.scalar()
    assert user is not None
    await session.close()

Here is the entire traceback for reference:
================================================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.10, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: C:\Users\myuser\Documents\visual-studio-code\my-project\backend-v2
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-4.6.2.post1, asyncio-0.24.0
asyncio: mode=Mode.STRICT, default_loop_scope=function
collected 3 items

tests\test_app.py .
tests\users\test_signup.py .F

======================================================================================================== FAILURES ========================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_signup_successful2 _________________________________________________________________________________________________

client = <httpx.AsyncClient object at 0x0000016B872ABB10>, session = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.AsyncSession object at 0x0000016B87096B90>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_signup_successful2(client, session):
        """Test user signup with valid data"""
        # Use ASGITransport explicitly
        transport = ASGITransport(app=app)
        async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="http://test") as client:
            # Define the request payload
            payload = {
                "first_name": "John",
                "last_name": "Doe2",
                "username": "johndoe2",
                "email": "testuser2@example.com",
                "password": "strongpassword123"
            }
            # Perform POST request
>           response = await client.post("/user/signup", json=payload)

tests\users\test_signup.py:77:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:1905: in post
    return await self.request(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:1585: in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:1674: in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:1702: in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:1739: in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:1776: in _send_single_request
    response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\asgi.py:157: in handle_async_request
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py:1054: in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py:113: in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py:187: in __call__
    raise exc
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py:165: in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py:185: in __call__
    with collapse_excgroups():
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\contextlib.py:158: in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_utils.py:83: in collapse_excgroups
    raise exc
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py:187: in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
middleware.py:27: in execution_timer
    response = await call_next(request)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py:163: in call_next
    raise app_exc
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py:149: in coro
    await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\trustedhost.py:36: in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py:85: in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py:62: in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py:62: in wrapped_app
    raise exc
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py:51: in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py:715: in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py:735: in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py:288: in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py:76: in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py:62: in wrapped_app
    raise exc
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py:51: in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py:73: in app
    response = await f(request)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py:301: in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py:212: in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
api\users\routes.py:36: in create_user_Account
    user_exists = await user_service.user_exists(email, session)
api\users\service.py:17: in user_exists
    user = await self.get_user_by_email(email, session)
api\users\service.py:12: in get_user_by_email
    result = await session.exec(statement)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlmodel\ext\asyncio\session.py:81: in exec
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py:201: in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlmodel\orm\session.py:66: in exec
    results = super().execute(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py:2362: in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py:2247: in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py:305: in orm_execute_statement
    result = conn.execute(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1418: in execute
    return meth(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py:515: in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1640: in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1846: in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1986: in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:2358: in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1967: in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:941: in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py:568: in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py:132: in await_only
    return current.parent.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return,attr-defined] # noqa: E501
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py:196: in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py:504: in _prepare_and_execute
    await adapt_connection._start_transaction()
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py:833: in _start_transaction
    self._handle_exception(error)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py:782: in _handle_exception
    raise error
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py:831: in _start_transaction
    await self._transaction.start()
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\transaction.py:146: in start
    await self._connection.execute(query)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py:350: in execute
    result = await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx:374: in query
    ???
asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx:367: in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol.query
    ???
asyncpg\protocol\coreproto.pyx:1094: in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.CoreProtocol._simple_query
    ???
asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx:966: in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._write
    ???
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py:365: in write
    self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  

self = <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=400 read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>, f = None, data = b'Q\x00\x00\x00*BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;\x00'

    def _loop_writing(self, f=None, data=None):
        try:
            if f is not None and self._write_fut is None and self._closing:
                # XXX most likely self._force_close() has been called, and
                # it has set self._write_fut to None.
                return
            assert f is self._write_fut
            self._write_fut = None
            self._pending_write = 0
            if f:
                f.result()
            if data is None:
                data = self._buffer
                self._buffer = None
            if not data:
                if self._closing:
                    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
                if self._eof_written:
                    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
                # Now that we've reduced the buffer size, tell the
                # protocol to resume writing if it was paused.  Note that
                # we do this last since the callback is called immediately
                # and it may add more data to the buffer (even causing the
                # protocol to be paused again).
                self._maybe_resume_protocol()
            else:
>               self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
E               AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\aidav2\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py:401: AttributeError
================================================================================================ short test summary info ================================================================================================= 
FAILED tests/users/test_signup.py::test_signup_successful2 - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
============================================================================================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 1.85s =============================================================================================== 


Edit:
For reference here is also my database/session.py code:
# database/session.py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from config import config

engine = AsyncEngine(create_engine(url=config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=config.DB_ECHO)) 


async def init_db():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:  # type: ignore
    Session = sessionmaker(  
        bind=engine,  
        class_=AsyncSession,
        expire_on_commit=False
    )
    async with Session() as session:  
        yield session



It seems that the only way to have a loop with self._proactor being None is if the process has been closed : [asyncio source code][https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d9e251223e8314ca726fc0be8b834362184b0aad/Lib/asyncio/proactor_events.py#L696]. I cannot help much more I'm not used to async stuff

I finally found the answer myself.
So I don't know if it's bug in asyncio or sth like that but in order for it to work properly you have to overwrite the async event_loop.
I created a conftest.py file to include my common configuration like this:
# tests/conftest.py
import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
import asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient
from httpx._transports.asgi import ASGITransport
from app import app
from database.session import get_session


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def session():
    """Create a fresh database session for each test"""
    async for session in get_session():
        yield session

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def client():
    """Create a new client for each test"""
    transport = ASGITransport(app=app)
    async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="http://test") as client:
        yield client

Now I can define my unit tests like this:
# tests/users/test_signup.py
import pytest
from sqlmodel import select
from models.users import User

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_signup_successful(client, session):
    """Test user signup with valid data"""
    payload = {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "username": "johndoe",
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "password": "strongpassword123"
    }
    
    response = await client.post("/user/signup", json=payload)
    
    # Assertions
    assert response.status_code == 201
    # additional assertions...


This will give you a warning in pytest v8.3.3 that overwriting the event_loop is deprecated and will not be supported much longer. However this warning can be suppressed by creating pytest.ini file in the project directory.
[pytest]
asyncio_default_fixture_loop_scope = function
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*event_loop fixture provided by pytest-asyncio has been redefined.*:DeprecationWarning

